# How to create temporary filename for image posted from Android App

Tags: php, android, android-file

```html
<?php
                    // Get image string posted from Android App
                    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
                 // Get file name posted from Android App
                
                  $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
                 
                 // Decode Image
                    $binary=base64_decode($base);
                    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
               
                   $file = fopen('uploads/'.$filename, 'wb');
                 // Create File
                    fwrite($file, $binary);
                    fclose($file);
                    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
                ?>
```

This my php code for get image string  and filename posted from Android App.I need to create temprory file name for the image.Can anyone help?.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to generate a unique temporary filename can you use a GUID perhaps?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Answer (score 1):

To create a temporary filename take a look at `tempnam()`, which "creates a file with a unique filename, with access permission set to 0600, in the specified directory."

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php